# Bootstrap 4 Scrollspy doesn't properly change active list item in IE

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I implemented Bootstrap 4 Scrollspy - [example with list-group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/#example-with-list-group) on my web page.

There is a problem I encountered: The class "active" doesn't properly applied to the last list item after clicking, mostly it occurs in IE.

For instance, if I click the last list item "上課學－the 10", the context of the scrollable area looks good, but the class "active" is on a wrong position.

Here's the code link to `<!-- https://jsfiddle.net/Anin_Huang/z1a84c3e/3/embedded/result,css,html,js -->`

Thank you!

## Update

I ended up finding the some issues on Bootstrap's official documentation when I used Internet Explorer 11 on Windows.
Check it out:
[bootstrap-scrollspy-list-group](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AninHuang/stackoverflow/master/bootstrap-scrollspy-list-group.gif)

Comment: please add your code here:)

Comment: It looks like it works perfect to me :https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptfZ3.png

Comment: @לבנימלכה Thanks! It works well in Chrome sometimes but mostly it occurs that issue in IE.

Comment: so please add to your question that the problem happens in IE

Comment: @לבנימלכה I see. thank you so much :-)